# logstash dynamic interpretation of fields

Tags: json, elasticsearch, text, logstash

I'm pretty new to elastic stack and I'm facing an issue when receiving events in logstash. These events are a json object, that can have in some cases first level keys:values, and in another cases the same key that was a string, can be a nested json object (below an example)

```
{
    error: "value1"
}
```

```
{
    error: { key-level2: "value2"}
}
```

Because usually this `error` is a string is mapped as `text` in index mapping, so when it contains a json object it generates the error : `failed to parse field [error] of type [text] in document ...`

Following different posts on https://discuss.elastic.co I've tried different approaches to detect json objects in logstash pipeline instead of strings but none of them seams to work.

I've tried the conditions :

```
filter {
    if "{" in [error] {
        json { source => "error" }
    }
}
```

```
filter {
    if [error] =~ "\A\{.+\}\z" {
        json { source => "error" }
    }
}
```

```
filter {
    if [error] =~ "^\{.*\}[\s\S]*$" {
        json { source => "error" }
    }
}
```

Can anyone provide me some guidance please ?

Answer (score 0):

The [`json` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html) will simply [tag your event](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html#plugins-filters-json-tag_on_failure) with `_jsonparsefailure` in case it cannot parse the value as JSON. You can then detect that tag (or the absence thereof) to apply the logic you need:

```
filter {
    json {
      source => "error"
      target => "error_details"
    }

    # this block gets executed if the value was not JSON (i.e. string)
    if "_jsonparsefailure" in tags {
      # do something with the text value?
    }

    # otherwise this block gets executed if the value was JSON
    # just replace the error field value with a string value
    else {
      mutate {
        replace => { 
          "error" => "%{[error_details][key-level2]}" 
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: That didn' work, but I missed an important piece of information, the index on which logs are arriving, has a strict mapping, which generates the error when receiving a field with the wrong mapping. So the question reformulated will be: is there any way to dynamically change a field type on logstash ? and if yes, could you provide any information about it please ?

Comment: Let's be precise here. The Logstash config worked, but the fact that your mapping is strict is the next thing that doesn't work and causes the document to fail indexing, is that correct? If yes, then you can try to use the [`mutate/convert` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-convert) in order to convert the field value to whatever is configured in your mapping.